# C++: LPWSTR prints as an address in cout

Tags: c++, pointers, unicode, cout

I have a variable of type `LPTSTR`, which I print to `std::cout` with `<<`. In an ANSI system (don't know exactly where it is determined) it worked fine, it printed the string. Now in a Unicode system I get a hex address instead of the string. So, why does `LPSTR` *(to which `LPTSTR` is resolved if `UNICODE` is not defined)* act differently from `LPWSTR` *(... if `UNICODE` is defined)* and how do I print the string pointed by the latter one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Unicode strings you want `wcout`.

You may be seeing hex because the ANSI/ASCII output stream doesn't know how to handle Unicode characters.

`LPTSTR` and `LPWSTR` are actually C-isms inherited from the C Windows API days.  For C++ I would strongly encourage you to use `std::string` and/or `std::wstring` instead.

If you need to roll your own macro, you'll want something like:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
std::wostream& COUT = std::wcout;
#else
std::ostream& COUT = std::cout;
#endif
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. And is there a standart macros that resolves to cout or wcout automatically?

Comment: And about using std::string - unfortunately, LPTSTRs are used in WinAPI functions so I have to use them. And to avoid unnesessary conversions I have to use them all along.

Comment: You can use the .c_str() method when you want a C-style null-terminated string to pass to the Windows API.

Comment: Concerning the standard macro: I'm not sure (I'm mostly doing C# these days).  If I remember correctly I had to roll my own but that was a few years ago.
It shouldn't be too difficult.  See edited response.

Comment: And what about strings returned from WinAPI functions? I'll have to create new string objects for every one to use it. And, most importantly, such strings are often members of WinAPI structures... Specifically, I have an array of such structures returned from a function. Converting strings from them to std::string is a no way.

Comment: Yes, if you're accessing the Windows API at a low level those things can be painful.  It depends on what kind of software you're developing.  If you're writing device drivers, you probably need to stick with the low-level API.  If, however, you're writing line-of-business applications, you will probably find it worth your while to "wrap" the low-level functionality.  For an example see the managed wrappers for the WiFi API at <http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/>.

Comment: I'd use `std::wostream& COUT = std::wcout;` and `std::wostream& COUT = std::cout;` instead of `#define COUT wcout` and `#define COUT cout`