# Coding a path in unicode c++

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I had a problem with opening UTF-8 path files. Path that has a UTF-8 char (like Cyrillic or Latin). I found a way  to solve that with `_wfopen` but the way a solved it was when I encode the UTF-8 char with UTF by hand (\Uxxxx).

Is there a function, macro or anything that when I supply the string (path) it will return the Unicode??

Something like this: 
https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

I tried with `MultiByteToWideChar` but it returns some Hex numbers that are not relavent.

Tried:

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}
std::wstring stemp = s2ws(x);
LPCWSTR result = stemp.c_str();
```

The result I get: `0055F7E8`

Thank you in advance

## Update:

I installed boost, and now I am trying to do it with boost. Can some one maybe help me out with boost.

So I have a path:
`wchar_t path[100] = _T("čaćšžđ\\test.txt");`

I need it converted to:

`wchar_t s[100] = _T("\u010d\u0061\u0107\u0161\u017e\u0111\\test.txt");`

Comment: `I tried with MultiByteToWideChar` That's how it's done in Win32. If it doesn't work for you, post the relevant code.

Comment: You do realize that Windows uses UTF-16, not UTF-8, right?

Comment: Use `CP_UTF8` (not CP_ACP) to convert _from_ UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Comment: @dxiv I changed that.. But still I get a strange code (looks like) hex. 0063F9BC my string is "test". It should be coded like this: \u0074 \u0065 \u0073 \u0074

Comment: I am printing the wrong result (I am printing the address):

std::wstring stemp = s2ws(x);
LPCWSTR result = stemp.c_str();
cout << result << endl;

Comment: Try to dump `buf` byte-by-byte, or inspect in the debugger.

Comment: Re `cout` vs `wcout`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873384/c-lpwstr-prints-as-an-address-in-cout

Comment: I added boost lib, can some one help me with that.. I think there is a way with boost/locale, but can't seem to get it to work..

Comment: The go-to solution for everything Unicode under C++ is [ICU](http://icu-project.org). Even Boost.Locale uses it as backend.

Comment: @Maverick: you can't print out a `wchar_t*` string using `std::cout`, it doesn't have an `operator<<` defined for `wchar_t*` input. You end up calling its `operator<<` for `void*` input, which is why you see the memory address printed instead. `std::cout` only works with `char*` strings, you have to use `std::wcout` instead for `wchar_t*` strings.

Comment: Your code is Windows-specific, and you're using Visual C++. So, just use wide literals. Visual C++ supports wide strings for file stream constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 on Windows, as well as showing the real values of the stored code units for both input and output:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;

    std::string s = "test";

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    std::cout << "Input `char` data: ";
    for (char c : s) {
      std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::wstring ws = convert.from_bytes(s);

    std::cout << "Output `wchar_t` data: ";
    for (wchar_t wc : ws) {
      std::cout << std::setw(4) << static_cast<unsigned>(wc) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Understanding the real values of the input and output is important because otherwise you may not correctly understand the transformation that you really need. For example it looks to me like there may be some confusion as to how VC++ deals with encodings, and what `\Uxxxxxxxx` and `\uxxxx` actually do in C++ source code (e.g., they don't necessarily produce UTF-8 data).

Try using code like that shown above to see what your input data really is.

---

To emphasize what I've written above; there are strong indications that you may not correctly understand the processing that's being done on your *input*, and you need to thoroughly check it.

The above program does correctly transform the UTF-8 representation of ć (U+0107) into the single 16-bit code unit `0x0107`, if you replace the test string with the following:

```
std::string s = "\xC4\x87"; // UTF-8 representation of U+0107
```

The output of the program, on Windows using Visual Studio, is then:

> Input `char` data: c4 87
>   Output `wchar_t` data: 0107

This is in contrast to if you use test strings such as:

```
std::string s = "ć";
```

Or

```
std::string s = "\u0107";
```

Which may result in the following output:

> Input `char` data: 3f
>   Output `wchar_t` data: 003f

The problem here is that Visual Studio does not use UTF-8 as the encoding for strings without some trickery, so your request to convert from UTF-8 probably isn't what you actually need; or you do need conversion from UTF-8, but you're testing potential conversion routines using input that differs from your real input.

---

> So I have a path: wchar_t path[100] = _T("čaćšžđ\test.txt");
>
> I need it converted to:
>
> wchar_t s[100] = _T("\u010d\u0061\u0107\u0161\u017e\u0111\test.txt");

Okay, so if I understand correctly, your actual problem is that the following fails:

```
wchar_t path[100] = _T("čaćšžđ\\test.txt");
FILE *f = _wfopen(path, L"w");
```

But if you instead write the string like:

```
wchar_t path[100] = _T("\u010d\u0061\u0107\u0161\u017e\u0111\\test.txt");
```

Then the `_wfopen` call succeeds and opens the file you want.

First of all, this has absolutely nothing to do with UTF-8. I assume you found some workaround using a `char` string and converting that to `wchar_t` and you somehow interpreted this as involving UTF-8, or something.

What encoding are you saving the source code with? Is the string `L"čaćšžđ\\test.txt"` actually being saved properly? Try closing the source file and reopening it. If some characters show up replaced by `?`, then part of your problem is the source file encoding. In particular this is true of the default encoding used by Windows in most of North America and Western Europe: "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252".

You can also check the output of the following program:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    wchar_t path[16] = L"čaćšžđ\\test.txt";

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (wchar_t wc : path) {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << static_cast<unsigned>(wc) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    wchar_t s[16] = L"\u010d\u0061\u0107\u0161\u017e\u0111\\test.txt";

    for (wchar_t wc : s) {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << static_cast<unsigned>(wc) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Another thing you need to understand is that the `\uxxxx` form of writing characters, called Universal Character Names or UCNs, is not a form that you can convert strings to and from in C++. By the time you've compiled the program and it's running, i.e. by the time any code you write could be attempting to produce strings containing `\uxxxx`, the time when UCNs are interpreted by the compiler as different characters is long past. The only UCNs that will work are ones that are written directly in the source file.

---

Also, you're using `_T()` incorrectly. IMO You shouldn't be using `TCHAR` and the related macros at all, but if you do use it then you ought to use it consistently: don't mix `TCHAR` APIs with explicit use of the *W APIs or `wchar_t`. The whole point of `TCHAR` is to allow code to be independent and switch between those `wchar_t` and Microsoft's "ANSI" APIs, so using `TCHAR` and then hard coding an assumption that `TCHAR` is `wchar_t` defeats the entire purpose.

You should just write:

```
wchar_t path[100] = L"čaćšžđ\\test.txt";
```

Comment: This is the exact thing I was looking for ... That you very very very much :D

Comment: Spoke too soon i doesn't work with latin char. For example that only converter converts `ć` into `0107` where your program `003f`...

Comment: @Maverick Did you check how the 'ć' character is represented in the _input_? This code _does_ correctly transform the UTF-8 representation of 'ć' into UTF-16. If you are getting output of `003f` then it's because your input is not the UTF-8 representation of 'ć'.

Comment: What do you mean, my input is: wchar_t path[100] = _T("čaćšžđ\\test.txt");

Comment: The problem i get is č đ ć Đ Č Ć are all the same 3f.. Do not know why... Maybe the problem is that your s is a  string and not a wstring.

Comment: @Maverick I think your problem is in the source file encoding you're using and has nothing to do with any conversions you could do in your program. Try resaving the file using File > Save main.cpp As... > Save With Encoding > UTF-8 with signature. Then `wchar_t path[100] = L"čaćšžđ\\test.txt";` should produce the string you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is Windows-specific, and you're using Visual C++. So, just use wide literals. Visual C++ supports wide strings for file stream constructors.

It's as simple as that ‐ when you don't require portability.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    wchar_t const path[] = L"cacšžd/test.txt";
    ifstream f( path );
    int ch;
    while( (ch = f.get()) != EOF )
    {
        cout.put( ch );
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this code is Visual C++ specific. That's reasonable for Windows-specific code. Possibly with C++17 we will have Boost file system library adopted into the standard library, and then for conformance g++ will ideally offer the constructor used here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was saving the CPP file as ANSI... I had to convert it to UTF-8. I tried this before posting but VS 2015 turns it into ANSI, I had to change it in VS so I could get it working.

I tried opening the cpp file with notepad++ and changing the encoding but when I turn on VS it automatically returns. So I was looking to `Save As` option but there is no encoding option. Finally i found it, in Visual Studio 2015

**File -> Advanced Save Options** in the Encoding dropdown change it to Unicode

[image]

One thing that is still strange to me, how did VS display the characters normally but when I opened the file in N++ there was **?** (like it was supposed to be, because of ANSI)?

Comment: Regardless of how you store the file simple narrow string literals are stored with C++ execution character set, which for Visual C++ is Windows ANSI, which varies according to which country Windows is installed for. And Visual C++ has no option to specify the execution character set. That's pretty ungood when you need portable code, but since you're using Windows API functions directly, just use wide literals.

Comment: @Maverick If you wrote the characters into Visual Studio's editor then Visual Studio could display them correctly even if the file it actually writes out and sends to the compiler contains '?'. I've seen this behavior myself. If you close and reopen the file then VS will display the '?'s.